# Linear map help needed, explain the theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that (v1,…,vn) is a basis of V and (w1,…,wm) is a basis of W. Then M is an invertible linear map between L(V,W) and Mat(m,n,F).

But all invertible matrices are square matrices, therefore, it means that m=n in this case, V and W have same dimensions?

If so, does it mean that V=W?

Comment: Is "$M$ is an invertible linear map" a hypothesis, or is it part of your argument?

Comment: proposition states that : suppose  that (v1,…,vn) is a basis of V and (w1,…,wm) is a basis of W. Then M is an invertible linear map between L(V,W) and Mat(m,n,F).

Comment: Note that the fact this is not true is quite important. If there exists such a invertible map M between W and V it means that W and V are isomorphic. This is helpful for example if you are thinking of a space with dimension 4 (for example polynomials of degree 3 or less) you can simply think of it as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You misunderstood what $M$ is.

$M$ is a linear transformation, which map linear transformation to its matrix according to the basis. $M$ is NOT a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$. $M$ is in fact a linear transformation from a space of dimension $mn$ to another space of dimension $mn$. Hence if you represent $M$ as a matrix, you will end up with a matrix $(mn)\times(mn)$. So all you can conclude from this is that $mn=mn$.

So what this means is that $L(V,W)$ is isomorphic to $M(m,n,F)$.

Comment: Oh, in other way, the dimension of the  set of all linear maps from V to W is equal to the dimension of Mat(m,n,F). But how do I understand the dim L(V,W) ? The number of linear maps?

Comment: $L(V,W)$ is also a vector space over the same field $F$. So the dimension is defined exactly like how one would normally define a dimension of any other vector space.

Comment: I think I get the feeling, thx so much, I totally off the track on this one

Comment: My understanding is M: L(V,W)---> Mat(m,n,F). And this linear map M is actually m-by-n matrix. Is this right?

Comment: @Hobbit6094:No. First, a linear map is not a matrix (they might be REPRESENTED by a matrix). Second, the matrix that represent it must be of dimension $(mn)\times(mn)$. That is, $mn$ row, $mn$ column.

Comment: could u explain mn row and mn column? Isn't matrix n*m or m*n. Why it becomes mn*mn

Comment: @Hobbit6094: a linear map from $V$ to $W$ would indeed be represented by a matrix of $M$ row, $n$ column, because $W$ have $m$ dimension and $V$ have $n$ dimension (in fact, this is what this theorem is about). But $M$ is not a linear map from $V$ to $W$. It is a linear map from $L(V,W)$ to $M(m,n,F)$. And $M(m,n,F)$ have dimension $mn$ (this should be obvious) so a matrix that represent $M$ will have $mn$ row. $L(V,W)$ have dimension $mn$ too (this might be less obvious), so a matrix that represent $M$ will have $mn$ column.

Comment: I don't know if my this question sounds stupid to you but Could u show me how the matrix that represent M look like in this case ?

Comment: @Hobbit6094:To represent $M$ using a matrix, you will need to pick a basis for $L(V,W)$ and $M(m,n,F)$. For example, you might pick a basis of $L(V,W)$ to consist of $mn$ linear transformation $T_{i,j}$ ($1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n$) with the indices ordered in lexical order, where $T_{i,j}$ is defined to be the unique linear transformation such that $T_{i,j}(v_{j})=w_{i}$ and $T_{i,j}(v_{k})=0$ for all $k\not=j$. We also pick a basis of $M(m,n,F)$ to consist of $mn$ matrix $A_{i,j}$ ($1\leq i\leq m,1\leq j\leq n$) with the indices ordered by lexical order, where $A_{i,j}$ is define to be...

Comment: ...the matrix where entries at row $i$ column $j$ is $1_{F}$, while every other entries are $0_{F}$. Then we will have $M(T_{i,j})=A_{i,j}$. Thus in this particular choice of basis, $M$ will be the $(mn)\times(mn)$ identity matrix.

Comment: could u also help me to understand how to prove this theorem? I've posted. here is the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861011/cant-understand-this-linear-algebra-theoremdesperately-seeking-for-help

Answer (score 1):

No $V$ and $W$ aren't necessary equal but they have the same dimension. For example let $V=\Bbb R^2$ and $W=\Bbb R_1[x]$ and $T\colon V\rightarrow W$ defined by
$$T(1,0)=1\quad;\quad T(0,1)=x$$
then the matrix $M$ of $T$ in the standard basis is $I_2$ invertible.

Comment: But the linear map M is a square matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

No. I can give you 2 linearly independent vectors in 3-space which span a plane and another two different from the former which span another plane. These vectors act as a basis for the two subspaces (with the same dimension=2), but they aren't equal.

Comment: So V is not necessary equal to W but the matrix must be square where n equals m?

Comment: Yeah. If n=m then you have a m$\times$m matrix which is square.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed $m$ must equal $n$.  In fact, $M$ defines an isomorphism between the two spaces, so the spaces $V$ and $W$ have equal dimension (and equal to $m=n$).

It doesn't necessarily mean $V=W$ though, for two main reasons:

- It's possible the elements of $V$ and $W$ are not even of the same type, e.g. $$V=\{(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4):v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$ and $$W=\left\{\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 \\ v_3 &v_4 \end{bmatrix} :v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4 \in \mathbb{R}\right\}.$$  In this case $V \cap W=\emptyset$.
- Even if $V$ and $W$ are subspaces of the same space, they still might be non-equal.  E.g. $$V=\mathrm{span}\{(0,1)\}$$ and $$W=\mathrm{span}\{(1,1)\}.$$

Comment: Thx so much. Because the book assumes the matrix with n columns and m rows, it confuses me because they usually just assumes a matrix with n*n

Comment: There are transformations like that (with $m \neq n$), but they can't be invertible.  It's more interesting to consider the $m=n$ case.