# Clarification: Suppose that $(v_1, \ldots ,v_n)$ is a basis of $V$ and $(w_1, \ldots ,w_n)$ is the basis of $W$ ...

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

====================================================

I don't understand the red lined sentence. I think T as vector of $L(V,W)$. If $M(T)=0$, then we know that $T$ belongs to $\text{Null}(M)$. But how do we conclude  $T(v_k)=0$ for $k=1,\ldots n$ ?

Comment: What is the definition of the map $M$?

Comment: Because $M(T)$ is the matrix representation of $T$, so the columns of the matrix are the components of $Tv_k$ for each $k$ with respect to the $w$ basis.

Comment: what I think is that M is linear map from vector space L(V,W) to vector space Mat(m,n,F)

Comment: Look up how your book define $M$. That should explain why if you know $M(T)=0$ then you will also know $T(v_{k})=0$.

Comment: @Gina:  The book in the previous paragraph states: If (v1,...,vn) is a basis of V and (w1,...,wm) is a basis of W, then for each T ∈ L(V,W), we have a matrix M(T) ∈ Mat(m,n,F). In other words, once bases have been fixed for V and W , M becomes a function from L(V , W ) to Mat(m, n, F).This linear map is actually invertible

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion stems from the fact that you are confusing what it means that $M$ is invertible. It doesn't mean that $M(T)$ is invertible for all $T$, it just means that the association of a matrix (with respect to given bases) to a linear map is bijective (and linear).

So, as Beni Bogosel already pointed out, the $k$-th column of $M(T)v_k$ being zero means that $Tv_k=0$. Hence, if $M(T)=0$ then $T=0$.

Answer (score 0):

(Why use "desperately seeking for help" in the title? It doesn't make people eager to see your question...)

Do you know the objects mentioned in the proposition? As I can figure out, $M(T)$ is the matrix associated to the linear application $T$ (corresponding to the basis $(v_i)$ of $V$ and $(w_i)$ of $W$). If the matrix associated to the linear map $T$ is the zero matrix, then the linear application is also zero.

Indeed, the column vectors of the matrix associated to a linear map are the coordinates of $Tv_k$ in the basis $(w_i)$. If the coordinates are zero then $Tv_k=0$.

Comment: (I couldn't figure out for like 5 hours now.....so "desperate" is legitimate word here i think....)

Comment: What I think is that M is a linear map from vector space L(V,M) to vector space Mat(m,n,F)

Comment: You could look at the definitions before this proposition and figure out what $M$ is...

Comment: The book in the previous paragraph states: If (v1,...,vn) is a basis of V and (w1,...,wm) is a basis of W, then for each T ∈ L(V,W), we have a matrix M(T) ∈ Mat(m,n,F). In other words, once bases have been fixed for V and W , M becomes a function from L(V , W ) to Mat(m, n, F).This linear map is actually invertible.  So I think M is not a representation of linear map from V to W

Comment: Yes, I get what you mean, but if you got this result from a book, you should search for the DEFINITION of M. $M$ is not arbitrary. The idea is that to every two bases you associate a matrix, and it is natural to think of the matrix associated to a linear application $T$, especially if in the proof you can see $M(T)$. Look for the definition of that matrix, which must be in there somewhere. $M(T)$ cannot be just an arbitrary matrix, because then the application you consider does not need to be linear and invertible.